# Displaying all the drives in the system in JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Here's my code i am unable to display all the drive's in my current system in a jtree, all it returns is some random java file, am a beginner and do not have much idea about how it is done, awaiting help..

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;


public class JTreeLits extends JPanel
{
 JTree tree;
 public JTreeLits()
 {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));
        DefaultMutableTreeNode rooter = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("FileSystem");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parent;
        File [] roots = File.listRoots();
        parent = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(roots);
        rooter.add(parent);

        tree = new JTree(rooter);
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
        add(tree);
 }
 private static void createAndShowGUI()
 {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TreeDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JTreeLits());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(250,400);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    createAndShowGUI();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look to [`FileSystemView.getRoots()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getRoots%28%29)<sup>1</sup>, which:

> Returns all root partitions on this system. For example, on Windows, this would be the "Desktop" folder, while on DOS this would be the A: through Z: drives.

1. As seen in [File Browser GUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784).

[image]

Comment: seen it done the changes and it shows

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Arrears.NewJTreeList.main(NewJTreeList.java:36)

where line 36 is

 File[] roots = fileSystemView.getRoots();

Comment: *"it shows Exception"*  1. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2. Always copy/paste error & exception output. 3. Use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.